# PHP Obfuscator for use with Code igniter code

Tags: php

I am looking for an obfucator for my PHP code, the code which I am trying to obfucate uses the codeigniter framework. The obfuscators that I have tried, don't seem to be able to do it.
Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336057/best-solution-to-protect-php-code-without-encryption

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [ionCube PHP Encoder](http://www.ioncube.com/)? It should obfuscate any kind of PHP file, so no reason for not working with codeigniter (as codeigniter is pure PHP)

Answer (score 1):

The [SD PHP Thicket Obfuscator](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/PHPObfuscator.jsp) robustly obfuscates PHP systems.

Many people attempt to use obfuscators thinking they take zero effort to set up.  You do have to configure them properly for your system. In particular, you need to make sure that any symbols that need to be seen outside the obfuscated code, are not obfuscated.   If you don't do that, no obfuscator will work for you.    This isn't actually all that hard if you use the help that the Thicket obfuscator offers in finding such problems.   Other obfuscators may offer similar help.  YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking in to [PHC](http://www.phpcompiler.org/doc/latest/runningphc.html#compiling-executables) recently.  From what I understand - which is noobish at this point - you can use it to write to C, have it compiled and then you use the executable.  Seems like this could be useful and fast(?).  It also allows you to do many other things like writing and reading XML along with compiling web apps.

Of course - a Codeigniter plugin for PHC may need to be developed by someone (scratches chin).

Let you know if it works for me!

Answer (score 0):

All the obfuticators out there are all independant of the framework you are using. They sit between php and the webserver they dont to know anything about your code.

Comment: This is a generic one ,why down vote ?