# Is there a way to protect a php script from being used without a valid license?

Tags: php

Is there any chance to restrict a php script from being shared and used without license? The scripts are paid and I am thinking what could be a way to prevent "sharing" this php script from happening. Is this possible or impossible? Because the code is open and I can't encrypt all of it.

I came to a conclusion and not sure if this can work or no?

A. The script asks user to enter a LICENSE/KEY

B. The license is sent to my licensing server and check whether the license is a valid one. (http://.... ?license=X)

C. The license is checked and the result is sent back to client server.

D. The script won't execute if the LICENSE is not valid.

Is that practically possible? or no?

Problem remains that the user can remove the license check part right (Since the code is open) ? But I could maybe encrypt that file and make it part of a core file that wouldn't have to be edited by user but still required file that if it was removed, the script won't function probably.. hmm I am lost :)

Comment: It's possible but how are you going to prevent someone from subverting your license validation algorithm since they have access to your PHP files.

Comment: what if I just delete the license part and say `$valid = true;`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best solution to protect PHP code without encryption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336057/best-solution-to-protect-php-code-without-encryption)

Comment: Trust me I have been thinking about that exact question for weeks :) Could I encrypt the validation part and make it a part of a required file inside the script? After all I do not want to PREVENT it all I know even the best scripts get hijacked I just want to do it to reduce sharing of these scripts, not all users are php gurus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I do not think this is actually possible.  If you can't encrypt it, then there is no way to prevent someone from just removing that portion of your script.  You could try to make it a pain in the butt to remove.  But no matter how hard to you make it, a determined coder could always remove the license check while leaving the primary script intact.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. What If I can encrypt one file (configuration file) and include the validation part in the configuration file? Would it be too easy to decrypt that file? As you said I want to make it a pain in the butt to remove and this could be one way because it won't be easy to create a configuration file from scratch and that specific file I really do not want any client to edit or touch.

Comment: I'm not sure.  I've never tried encrypting my files, so I'm not sure how it would work.  I imagine that no matter how you do it, it would always be possible for someone to remove the dependency on the encrypted file.  And I dunno if there's a module for the php parsing engine to allow it to handle encrypted files or not (so that you could just encrypt everything).  There might be if you look...