# Coding CallBack Tracker

Tags: php, curl

I did  script which i am going to sell but before i am going to encode into Ioncube how do i make a callback tracker to tell my website who is using my script, What domain ip it is? if i found out that is not the exact license i can banned the script or ip?

i have this in mind but how can i make the script disabled when it track from my database its a pirated version?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://mywebsite.com/validationwebsite/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$data = array(
    'dateofexpire' => '',
    'ip' => $ipaddress,
    'domainname' => $domainname,
    'email' => $email,
    'serialno' => $serialno
);
```

Anyone could help it would be appreciated =)

Please advise

Comment: The simplest way is to host the functionality on your own site as a SOAP/REST app.

Comment: hi i dont know whats SOAP/REST? can you elaborate? i know its xml reading somesort of string only

Answer (score 1):

> how can i make the script disabled when it track from my database its a pirated version

You can't.  ionCube's bytecode obfuscation is trivial to remove.  Pirate groups have even created *paid services* that will do so.  Ironic, eh?  This means that the person creating the pirated version will simply remove the code that disables the script before distributing it.

Your best shot at minimizing losses by piracy is to make your application less likely to be pirated.  Choose a fair price for your feature set and appropriate licensing terms.  If your application is targeted at the mass market, consider also making a free version with a smaller feature set.  People that might otherwise pirate the full version can use that one instead, and may be happy to do so.  If your application is highly specialized and targets a small market, you should consult your lawyer.

See also: [Best solution to protect PHP code without encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336057/best-solution-to-protect-php-code-without-encryption)

Comment: because i have read vbulletin dosent have the ioncube or zend encoding but they still track avaliable sites that are using the script.

Because i am just selling this script to my client so i am scared that he just clone it out and sell to another person.

Is there any suggestion that i can do? i am open to any solution.

Comment: vBulletin's calls home are just as effectively removed as any others.  The piracy community latched on to the term "nulled" or "nullified" when distributing versions that had the call home removed.  If you are selling *licenses* to your software, your best protection is a real and proper contract to establish the terms of the license.  Talk to your lawyer.