# PHP process the code without decode it

Tags: php, encryption

My php hosting injected by unknown code. I don't post the whole file,

> $x0d = "b\x61se\x364\137dec\x6f\144\145";

How can the PHP process this line of code without any function to decode.

\x61 = a , what is \x61? how can web server understand this character? I try with HEX / OCT encoding also can't provide me \x61

I give an example inside the code, the below code will execute `sha1`

```
$a = "s\x68\x61\061"; 
echo $a("hello");
```

*The whole file does not have any `eval()` function inside there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. After I referring to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983809/obfuscate-encode-encrypt-php-system-function-names), I understand it is PHP string type.

http://www.php.net/language.types.string

**Escaped characters** in double quote

[0-7]{1,3} : the sequence of characters matching the regular expression is a character in octal notation

\x[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2} : the sequence of characters matching the regular expression is a character in hexadecimal notation

hexadecimal can refer from here:
http://www.ascii.cl/