# i had complete my website but without protect?

Tags: javascript, php, api

I have my design for my website that consists of several web pages and class ,and that these pages call functions inside this class. Now that I have completed the site and there are customers who want to buy a copy from this site, what is required is to help me. How can I save the site from theft or copying and pasting?
I mean, I want to sell a copy and not steal it? How can I keep the main code 
i think api not good

Comment: If you want to restrict others to copy your code. basically there's no  way to do that . as  everything  that is rendered in the HTML can copy  however they won't have any access on  the Controller/Classes behind the  rendered HTML.

Answer (score 0):

All codes in PHP can only be seen in server side, so the client user can not copy the codes.

Comment: The page is a web service
Which means that I can sell it to more than one person

Answer (score 0):

to protect the code, you can make obfuscator javascript code (or/and obfuscator php).

if you are selling a site code, you need to add a license (license file + each file with a code in the comments indicate the author)

Comment: did you have any sources?

Comment: If obfuscator  then  google "obfuscator php online" and "obfuscator js online".

If license (I did not use such licenses only for free licenses (MIT, GPL)), i think you can take the product of competitors and see how they have done 
(you can write something of your own).

Good answers are here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336057/best-solution-to-protect-php-code-without-encryption